# Trying to spread out difference between cells in list

Tags: python

I have a list that moves around 100 by a small bit (see the list in the code below). For the days that I have 0, I would like to spread out the difference of the previous cells.

*(I'm counting zero as the first cell in the text below, because python)*

To give an example, the `original_list` below has the value `100.41191500000001` in cell 2, and `0` in cells 3,4,5. I would like to take the change `abs(original_list[1]-original_list[2])=1,26108000000001`, and spread it out over the three days. So basically I would like cell 2 to be occupied by `original_list[1]+(1.26108000000001/4)`, cell 3 to be `new_list[2] + (1.26108000000001/4)`, cell 4 to be `new_list[3] + (1.26108000000001/4)`, and finally cell 5 to also be `new_list[4] + (1.26108000000001/4)`.

I divide by four because I want the change that happened between cell 1 and 2, to be spread out evenly between cells 1 to 5.

The code below presents what I've tried, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
original_list = [98.87464, 99.150835, 100.41191500000001, 0, 0, 0, 101.650165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101.850421, 0, 99.970131, 100.244205, 98.550495, 0, 0, 97.496535, 97.971645]
new_list = [0 for i in range(len(original_list))]

for i in range(len(original_list)):
    j = i
    if original_list[i] == 0:
        while original_list[j] == 0:
            j += 1
    elif original_list[i] != 0:
        new_list[i] = original_list[i]
    if j != i:

        for k in range(0,j-i+1):
            new_list[i+k] = new_list[i-1] + abs(new_list[i]-new_list[i-1])/(j-i+1)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best approach as it will not give your expected result.

1. The `for` loops iterates over all the elements of the range. You have an inner `for` loop in the `if j != i:` block which calculate the replacement values for the following 0's. When the control is returned to the main `for` loop, it is going to recalculate those values, giving unexpected numbers.
2. I think your math to calculate `new_list[i+k]` is wrong. If I understood correctly, it does not reproduce what you describe in your question.

In your case a `while` loop is recommended. In the case where `original_list[i] != 0:` you increment the index by 1, in the case where `original_list[i] == 0:` you need to set the index of the proper value so that it corresponds to the next non null element in your original list, which should be `i = j`.
And of course you need to fix the math.

I would wrote the code in this way:

```
new_list = []

i = 0
while i < len(original_list):
    if original_list[i] == 0:
        j = i+1
        while original_list[j] == 0 and j < len(original_list):
            j += 1 #searching the index of the next non null value
        #please check if the following math is what you really need, fix it in case.
        diff = original_list[j] - new_list[-1]
        inslist = [new_list[-1] + (k*diff)/(j-i+1) for k in range(1, (j-i+1))]
        new_list.extend(inslist)
        i = j
    elif original_list[i] != 0:
        new_list.append(original_list[i])
        i += 1
```

You can compare the two list with: `print([(o, n) for o, n in zip(original_list, new_list)])` and see if each original - new pair of values is correct.